# Webpage visit counter in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am making a simple static website in React as I am a newbie in learning this technology. I want to create a simple counter which shows the total number of visits on my website. it would be a great help if someone can help me creating this.

Comment: You should add to your question your attempts to get what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

 function Counter() {
 const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

 useEffect(() => {
 const storedCount = localStorage.getItem("pageVisits");
 const initialCount = storedCount ? Number(storedCount) : 0;
 setCount(initialCount + 1);
 localStorage.setItem("pageVisits", initialCount + 1);



 }, []);

 return (
 <div>
  Total Visits: {count}
 </div>
);
}
```

export default Counter;
Add this component in app component but this is not a proper solution
Proper solution would be like using
backend api and update the counter
And rendering the counter in UI .

Hope this helps

Comment: Counting visits in `localStorage` makes no sense, since the user will only see his own visits, while the question asks for total number of visits.

Comment: yep , i have made it clear while adding the code , and provided a legit way as well

Comment: You should not be posting an answer if you know you are not addressing the actual question. You should instead look for a different question where your post might be relevant. If you have to say "this is not a proper solution" you can already see that there is no point in posting that code. And saying "Proper solution would be like using backend api" does not constitute a worth wile answer, it could have been a comment instead.